# Inner Join statement for two different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently trying to inner join these two tables:
[Prize table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CkUm.jpg)[Entry table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOmfE.jpg)

I've come up with this so far:

```
SELECT  entry.event_id, entry.horse_id, entry.place, prize.money
FROM entry
INNER JOIN prize
ON entry.place = prize.place
ORDER BY event_id, horse_id;
```

But this is the expected outcome I'm looking for:

[Expected Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqzFi.jpg)

Comment: what is the outcome you are getting now?

Comment: kindly describe your error message

Answer (score 2):

You must also join on `event_id`:

```
SELECT entry.event_id, entry.horse_id, entry.place, prize.money
FROM entry
INNER JOIN prize
ON entry.place = prize.place and entry.event_id = prize.event_id
ORDER BY entry.event_id, entry.horse_id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e32c7b3dc3f7b3af7da1693088857de1).
Results:

```
> event_id | horse_id | place | money
> -------: | -------: | ----: | ----:
>      101 |      101 |     1 |   120
>      101 |      102 |     2 |    60
>      101 |      201 |     3 |    30
>      102 |      201 |     2 |     5
>      103 |      201 |     3 |    40
```